# How can I get all the Stack Overflow tags to use in a different project?

Tags: support, tags

I am working on a simple web-based forum. I like the tags used by Stack Overflow and I would like to integrate the tags and descriptions into my website. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Should be migrated from meta to stackoverflow.com

Comment: No, this should not be migrated anywhere. It is a question about Stack Overflow and is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get all tags via the [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) or the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

The data dump is large but once you have it the easiest to get all tag data from. The API only lets you load tag wiki data for 20 tags at a time, so is going to be slower if you want to do a one-time extraction.

As an alternative to the data dump you could use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) to give you query results in CSV form, but [there are limitations in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213050/why-cant-i-pull-in-all-the-so-users-from-data-explorer/234774#234774) on how much data you can load via that method.

Take into account that that data is [*licenced* under CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). You have to attribute the original author(s).

Comment: It's clear that descriptions has authors. What about tag names alone - are they covered by CC BY-SA 3.0 individually, or as whole collection of names or tag names has some other license/restrictions?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, IANAL: From a legal standpoint, individual tags would each be copyrighted by their creator and would need to each be attributed to their original author. However, you rapidly get into arguments about how much originality is needed for a tag to be considered a copyright-able "work". But, that immediately dives into a country-by-country slog through copyright law. The only safe route is to individually credit each to their author, as required under [CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) and the [SE TOS § 3](https://stackexchange.com/legal).